# Как передать Всю коллекцию ListBox по Cookies на другую форму?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookie, asp.net-webforms

Есть две формы. В одной я заполняю ListBox В другой есть таблица, в которую нужно записать Текст Item-ов из ListBox и Value этих Item-ов. Как через Cookie можно передать коллекцию или массив Item-ов? Возможно ли это или нужно искать другой способ заполнить таблицу?

Comment: Сериализуйте данные, например в json, и пишите в куку.

Comment: @aepot А средствами C# это сделать нельзя?

Comment: Средствами .net в C# и сериализуйте.